# ports information of docker container

Tags: docker

I'm new in docker.

I have my docker container up and running. I can see it with command `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
426e21a1bbbd        my_app    "./docker/app/entryp…"   2 hours ago        Up 2 hours            0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp         my_app_1
```

In above result, the `PORTS` column shows `0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp`

But if I run command `docker port 426e` it gives result `3000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3000`

So the two results are in different order of the `->`. I get confused by this, which part is meant for my host machine and which is used by container?

Answer (score -1):

The side with the "0.0.0.0" is the host side.  That is the IPv4 address of the host interface the network connection is bound to, as in the **bind**(2) system call, where "0.0.0.0" is a special address (*you cannot connect to 0.0.0.0*) meaning "all host interfaces".